Field Usage In Outbound Messages Not Visible
If a field is used in an outbound message it does not show up under "Where is this used?" for some reason. However, if I try to delete this field I suddenly get an error that it's being used and I cannot delete it.
So, why does it not show up in the usage list in the first place? And how can I determine where that field is being used? Any insights on this weird behavior?

You can always download all the metadata to an IDE project and search for the API name of the field to find use cases not covered by the Where is this used feature

Great solution! I do this all the time but somehow I didn't consider this here. Is there a list of limitations for that feature? And if so - why? It's not like the functionality isn't there as it will alert you about the usage when you're trying to delete the field.

I think (others can correct me) that Where is this used relies on the Metadata Dependency objects in the Tooling API whereas your error involves the Metadata API.  So, alignment issues could arise
